# Converting UTF-8 path to wide characters on English-based system throws exception

Tags: c++, utf-8, internationalization

I have an app that scans folder paths and presents them to a user.  I have long been using a simple utility to convert from UTF-8 to wide strings.  It has worked very well.  But today it started throwing an exception and I need to figure out what to do.

This is the function.

```
inline std::wstring convertutf8(const std::string& p) 
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> wconv;
    return wconv.from_bytes(p.c_str());
}
```

Today the utility attempted to convert this string for the first time and thew an exception

> I:\Scans\Nouvelles numérisations

This was a folder path created when I ran a French version of some other application and saved something to a folder that my app scans.  (I am running on a system with English-US as my locale).

This path caused the Standard C++ library to throw a range_error exception (with "bad conversion" as the text) from inside of the from_bytes function, the standard library appears to be unable to convert the character with the accent mark...

> é

I can see several ways to deal with the situation, including catching the exception (and returning "") or perhaps having a default error string returned in such a case.  (wstring_convert has a facility for this in the constructor). But I need to understand this better.

I foolishly hoped that using wstring_convert with codecvt_utf8 would let me deal with such situations.  Until now my application appears to have properly handled even Chinese paths with aplomb.  So I am surprised that this one is giving me trouble

When I look at the text of the problem character in the debugger (and those around it) I see the following

```
CHAR   DEC     HEX
----   ---     ----
 'n'   110     0x6e
 'u'   117     0x75
 'm'   109     0x6d
 'é'   -23     0xe9
 'r'   114     0x72
 'i'   105     0x69
```

Do those numbers represent "proper" UTF-8 representation?  I wouldn't even know.  Internationalization is not a strong suit for me.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Missing something simple?  This is part of an app that scans folders and presents them to the user for navigating.  I would like to be able to handle the case of a path with such characters, properly convert them and continue.

Can someone give me some guidance as to what I ***should*** do in this case to be able to handle such a path on an English-based system?

Comment: "Do those numbers represent "proper" UTF-8 representation?" According to this here https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl `0xe9` is the  unicode for `é` and the UTF8 representation is `c3 a9`. So it seems like it indeed didn't convert it properly.

Comment: @Blaze you mean that it complained correctly about e9 72 not being correct UTF-8.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Indeed. The hex listed, which supposedly should be UTF-8, is not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::wstring_convert` does the right thing by throwing an exception.

`0xe9` is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence for the character `é`. Only code points in the range 0-127 (basic ASCII) do not need to be specially encoded.

A valid UTF-8 byte sequence for the character `é` would look like this ([try for yourself](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode)):

```
0xC3, 0xA9
```

> what I should do in this case to be able to handle such a path on an
>   English-based system?

This case is an error in the input and should be handled as such. For instance, report the error to the user, so they fix the input.

Comment: The input in this case comes from a C# .NET app scanning a directory, passing a string into a C++.CLI layer where it then enters my C++ SDK.  Sounds like the conversion at that middle layer is doing the wrong thing.  It's one of the few conversions I wasn't handling myself.  Thanks.  In the very least it's good to know that the problem is the input string itself.  Gives me a plan of attack.